# Update the formula to 'Search' next name if the first listed name results #N/A

Tags: excel-formula

I am running this formula which is working fine for first listed name in the cell. I would like to update the formula to 'Search' next name and do the Vlookup, if the first listed name results #N/A.

- The first row contains: `Jane; John; David;`
- Second row contains: `Mary; Molly; Dan; Thomas;`
- Third row contains: `Lily; Dove; Lucy; Mike;`

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(F86, SEARCH(";",F86,1)-1),UserDepReport!A:R,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: please also provide an example with expected outcome.

Comment: what if two names return a value, do you want only the first?

Comment: If the Vlookup cant find 'Jane' in the UserDepReport sheet it should look for the 'John' and if 'John'' is not found then look for 'David' in the UserDepReport. If all the names are not found in the UserDepReport from the Cell it should return #N/A.

Comment: What the max number of names in the cell?

Comment: Max number of names varies from 2-15.

Comment: The above formula is working fine for the first listed name. =VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2, SEARCH(";",F2)-1),UserDepReport!A:R,3,FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate the names and test each one then return an array of positive finds to an index to return the array of responses then pick the first one.  Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(E:E,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",""))))-1)*999+1,999)),D:D,0)),MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",""))))-1)*999+1,999)),D:D,0)*{1,1}))))),1)
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This returns the first match based on the order in A1.

[image]

If the order precedent were the list of names(Column D in my photo) a simpler formula can be used:

```
=INDEX(E:E,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($D$1:$D$5)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("; "&$D$1:$D$5&";","; " &A1))),1))
```

Note the different return between B3 and C3:

[image]

---

We can also leverage the `vba.Split()` with a simple UDF:

```
Function MYSPLIT(STR As String, del As String) As String()
    MYSPLIT = Split(STR, del)
End Function
```

This allows a shorter formula:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(E:E,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(MYSPLIT(A1,";")),D:D,0)),MATCH(TRIM(MYSPLIT(A1,";")),D:D,0)*{1;1}))))),1)
```

Still an array formula that must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Put the code in a module attached to the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **ListName** being Column A of your `UserDepReport` sheet;
- **ListValue** being Column C of your `UserDepReport` sheet.

Try one of the following **array formulas** that you **MUST** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar otherwise they will not function correctly. Then you can simply drag the formula down to apply across.

```
=INDEX(ListValue,MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(MID(D2,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH("; "&ListName&";","; "&D2),LEN(D2))),LEN(D2)),";",REPT(" ",100)),1,100)),ListName,0))
```

Replace `D2` to suit your actual case.

> The logic is to use **SEARCH** function to find out if any of the names from your data table is present in the string, then use **MIN+IFERROR** functions to return the first presence of the valid name, then use **TRIM+MID+REPT** functions to extract the name, and lastly use **INDEX+MATCH** to return the corresponding value.

or

```
=INDEX(ListValue,MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D2,";",REPT(" ",100)),(MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(ListName,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(D2,LEN(D2)-1),";","</s><s>"))&"</s></t>","t/s"),0),LEN(D2)))-1)*100,100)),ListName,0))
```

Replace `D2` to suit your actual case.

> The logic of this formula is similar to the first one, whereas this one used **FILTERXML** to extract all the names in the string in an array, then use **MATCH** function to find out if any of the names from your data table is present in the string, then use **MIN+IFERROR** functions to return the first presence of the valid name, and the rest is the same as the first function.

[image: Solution]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)